# Prove $\Bbb Z_n$ is a group under modulo addition: the associative part.

Tags: group-theory, number-theory

Why is $\Bbb Z_n =\{0,1,2,3,4,...,n-1\}$ a group under modulo addition?

Only assosiative part is needed. That is, I am stuck proving that for $a,b,c \in \Bbb Z_n$, we have:
$$(a + b \pmod{ n} + c) \pmod {n} = a + (b + c \pmod{n}) \pmod n.$$

Or maybe more clearly stated. With $+_n$ denoting "$+ \pmod{n}$":
$(a +_n b) +_n c = a +_n ( b +_n c)$.

-Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The elements of $\Bbb Z_n$ are *equivalence classes* of integers, like so:

$$[a]_n:=\{b\in\Bbb Z:n\mid a-b\},$$

where $a\in \Bbb Z.$

Addition is defined as follows:

$$[a]_n+_n[b]_n:=[a+b]_n.$$

Now the associativity you require follows from associativity of addition: for any $[a]_n,[b]_n,[c]_n\in\Bbb Z_n$, we have

$$\begin{align}
[a]_n+_n([b]_n+_n[c]_n)&=[a]_n+_n[b+c]_n\\
&=[a+(b+c)]_n\\
&=[(a+b)+c]_n\\
&=[a+b]_n+_n[c]_n\\
&=([a]_n+_n[b]_n)+_n[c]_n.
\end{align}$$

Comment: Could you maybe elaborate a little on the second equal sign. The: [a]n+n[b+c]n =[a+(b+c)]n. Why this is true is unclear to me. Thanks.

Comment: Sure, @mem_surf. Let $x=b+c$. Then we have $$\begin{align} [a]_n+_n[b+c]_n&=[a]_n+_n[x]_n\\ &=[a+x]_n\\ &=[a+(b+c)]_n.\end{align}$$

Comment: Maybe my understanding of  modulo is completely wrong, but how is $[a]_n +_n [b]_n = [a+b]_n$.

Comment: It's by definition of $+_n$, @mem_surf.

Comment: A less glib answer, @mem_surf, would be to establish that the definition is [well-defined](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Modulo_Addition_is_Well-Defined#:~:text=The%20modulo%20addition%20operation%20on,%2By(modm).).

Comment: Ah of cause, my problem was $[a]_n +_n [b]_n = [a+b]_n$. However, I just realized why you implicitly wrote that this is trivial. Thanks for the answer.

Comment: You're welcome, @mem_surf.